# Find a,k,c and d in $a\sin(k(x-c))+d$ given the graph

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

[image]

Note: the exercise specifies that I use the model $a\sin(k(x-c))+d$

I have already found the amplitude $a$ and the vertical shift $d$, but I am not sure about $k$ and $c$.

To find $k$ I did:

$$\frac{1 \text{ period}}{12 \text{ units}} = \frac{y}{2\pi } \Leftrightarrow \\
y = \pi/6$$

$$\frac{2\pi}{|k|} = \pi/6 \Leftrightarrow k = 12$$

Then I tried to use the point $(14;4)$ to find $c$

$$4 = 2\sin(12(14-c))+5 \Leftrightarrow \\
-1/2 = \sin(168-12c) \Leftrightarrow \\
???$$

This doesn't look correct... how do I solve this? Is there a more straightforward way to find the phase shift?

Comment: What is $y{}{}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\sin [k(x-c)]$, since $\sin$ is periodic every $2\pi$, for $n\in\mathbb Z$,

$$\begin{align*}
\sin[k(x-c)] &= \sin [k(x-c)+2\pi n]\\
&= \sin\left[k\left(x + \frac{2\pi n}k -c\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$

So in the scale of $x$, $\frac{2\pi}{k}$ is the period. ($\frac{k}{2\pi}$ is the frequency and $k$ is the angular frequency.) In this case,

$$\frac{2\pi}{k} = 12 \implies k = \frac{2\pi}{12}$$

---

Substitute $(14,4)$,

$$\begin{align*}
\sin\left[\frac{2\pi}{12}(14 -c)\right] + 5 &= 4\\
\sin\left[\frac{2\pi}{12}(14 -c)\right] &= -1\\
\frac{2\pi}{12}(14 -c) &= -\frac{2\pi}{4} + 2\pi n\\
14-c &= -3 + 12n\\
c &= 17 - 12n
\end{align*}$$

So you may choose $n = 0$ to give $c = 17$, or choose $n = 1$ to give a smaller positive $c = 5$.

See the black point at $x=5$? That is exactly like the curve $y = \sin x$ at $(0,0)$ where both curves are going up from equilibrium, and $c=5$ is no coincidence.